# Should I pay off my car loan within the year?

Tags: loans, credit-score, car, debt, interest

I saw [another question like this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11605/should-i-pay-off-my-car-loan-within-first-year-or-wait-until-at-least-one-year-h), but I am in a bit of a different situation.

I am 19 years old, in college, and have no credit history.

I saved up enough money to buy a car, but decided to get a loan and have the payments pulled automatically from my account so that I can build credit.

While I'm paying off the loan, I'm required to have full coverage insurance (and thus a higher premium than I would like).

My plan was to pay off the loan in 6 months and then reduce my coverage to liability, however I've heard that the loan won't show on your credit report correctly (which was the whole point of getting the loan in the first place!)

After I pay off the car loan, I plan to get a credit card and pay it off every month to continue building my credit.

**Would it be better to pay off the loan early and save some money, or pay it off for the entire 18 month period and hemorrhage money the whole time?**

Comment: Pay the loan off.  There are better (cheaper) ways to build credit.

Comment: Only get rid of the full coverage insurance if you can afford to lose your car.

Comment: Is [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/11605/10997) the one you saw?  What do you think is different about your situation than that question?

Comment: @BenMiller yes that was the question I saw, but he actually has credit while I have nothing. I want to move off campus the summer of 2018 so I'd need credit for that. I'm not sure, but I thought that starting up my credit would be different from continuing his.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to show 6 months of on-time payment then to have no payment records at all.

Comment: If you can afford it, you should pay off the loan immediately. You're saying you *want* to pay interest, just to build credit? That's *crazy*. There are FAR better ways to build credit. I've never paid any interest on anything in my life, and my score is near 800. Get a credit card, start using it for every purchase you make, and pay it off in full every month.

Comment: What interest rate are you paying on the car loan?

Comment: @TTT my interest rate is 15% for an 18 month, $3,000 loan. Total interest at the end would be under $350. That's not a ridiculous amount, but my total cost of full coverage insurance over that time period would be much much more.

Comment: @A.Kirk That's a bummer of an interest rate, ditch it, imo. Have you applied for a credit card already?

Comment: It would be better to wait a while and buy car for cash. Taking credit for consumption goods like cars is generally a very bad idea. But it's your life, your choice.

Comment: What is the value of the car and what is the price difference of the car insurance with and without full coverage?

Comment: @TTT My bank (which is giving me the loan) valued the car at $4600 and I bought it for $3900, taking out $3000 in loans and putting $900 down. I haven't checked what the insurance would be without full coverage, but with it is $113 a month with about a $700 6-month premium. So I would be paying almost half of what I paid for the car originally just on the insurance over the course of 12 months. My dad says to switch my insurance just to liability and uninsured motorist as soon as possible so that I can save money.

Comment: Also, in reference to the credit card, my twin sister has looked into getting one for the same reasons I started a car loan. We'd prefer to go through our bank but because of our low credit scores we'd need to apply for a "starter" secure card, which requires that you put at least a $250 deposit down and that's your credit limit. Not only that but there's a $35 annual fee simply for having it. We're poor college kids and she doesn't have a job during the school year so she decided it just wasn't worth it. What are everyone else's thoughts?

Comment: Paying the banks free (for them) money just to be able to participate in the loans and credits game sounds, sorry, ridiculous. If you have the money to pay for something, pay it and it's yours from day one. Why build up debt just to be able to build up even more debt? That sounds like "where can I get marijuana in order to prepare for crack?"

Comment: Here is a similar question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27009/does-paying-off-a-car-loan-increase-or-reduce-a-persons-credit-score

Comment: Read my answer to this question (https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46018/how-to-build-a-u-s-credit-history-as-a-worker-on-a-visa/46023#46023) for how to build credit quickly.

Comment: Wow, that's really reasonable insurance for a 19-year-old male.

Comment: Haha, I am female and I took a drivers ed course, have a motorcycle license, and haven't ever been in an accident.

Comment: hi @A.Kirk - something to consider in the future, it's a shame to spend so much on a car.  If you'd bought a $800 car (which would be utterly identical to your current car), think how far ahead you'd be in every issue?  And - **you've absolutely hit the nail on the head** - you don't insure, at all, an $800 car.  (Only the legal minimum third-party required in your state.)  I would urge you to go out and waste $4000 on, say, clothes or haircuts (which have huge, spectacular, tangible and real benefits). Cars are, simply, an utter waste of money.

Comment: If you want an illuminating experience.  Drive over to the nearest "CarMax" chain.  For free, they will give you a there-and-then quote on how much your car is actually literally worth **right now**.  You will be illuminated.  :/

Comment: @A.Kirk You're happy to pay $350 in interest over 18 months (over $19/month on average), but can't imagine paying $35 in fees over 12 months (less than $3/month on average)? And 15% interest rate in a developed economy is virtually *never* a good rate. In fact, I'd go as far as to say that it's a *horrible* rate in almost any situation. Even with poor finances, you should be able to get half of that, easily, especially if the car is valued at 1.5x the loan amount.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm planning on paying the car off over 6 months, which would still have interest yeah, but on the total cost of the car it's relatively small. The $35 isn't a huge deal to me (even though it seems like I'm spending money to have the right to spend money), it's the $250 deposit. I know I would get it back eventually, but it's a lot of money to drop just so I can have a credit card.

Answer (score 35):

Personally, I don't think that the interest from the car loan is worth the credit history you're building through it. There are other ways to build credit that don't require you to pay interest, like the credit card you mentioned (so long as you keep paying off the balance). So I'd go that route: ditch the auto loan and replace it with a line of consumer credit. Just be careful not to overspend because the card will likely have a higher interest rate than your loan.

Comment: It's rational for an individual to run their expenses through a credit card to build credit or earn rewards. But as a society, the costs (e.g., interest, penalties, annual fees, and the 1 to 3 percent cut of each merchant transaction) probably outweigh the benefits. It's kind of an unfortunate paradox.

Comment: Cost of merchant transactions might very cost nothing  (depending on where you live).  And a credit card can be paid off automatically just like OP's car payments.

Comment: I'll note in passing that a sentence of the form “[cost] is not worth [benefit]” is, besides just plain weird, possibly confusing to foreigners.

Answer (score 21):

Something I'd like to plant firmly into your mind - If you're able to save up enough money to buy the things you want outright, credit will be of little use to you.

Many people find once they've accumulated very good credit scores by use of good financial habits, that they rarely end up using credit, and get little out of having a 'great' credit score compared to an 'average' credit score.

Of course, a lot of that would depend on your financial situation, but it's something to keep in mind.

As stated by others, and documented widely online, you **don't need to make payments on a loan or carry a card balance to build your credit history.**

Check your credit on a popular site, such as Credit Karma (**No affiliation**).

There, you'll see a detailed breakdown of the different areas of your credit profile that matter; things like:

- Your utilization: Keep this under 30% of your credit limits on cards for good scores, and 0% is okay too
- Your average age of account history - longer is better
- Your number of open accounts, and total accounts
- Your payment history - the number of monthly payments you haven't missed - Not having a balance counts too.
- The types of accounts you've had - Banks / Lenders may want you to have some actual loan history in your profile before some other types of loans, like a home loan, but not a requirement by far, and depends on the lender what their criteria are.
- Records entered against you like judgements, collections, bankruptcies, etc.

The best thing I could recommend is get a credit line or credit card, and use it responsibly. Carrying a balance will waste money on interest, much like the car payment. Just having it and not over-using it (Or not using it at all) will 'build' your credit history.

Of course, some institutions may close your account after X number of years of inactivity.

With this in mind, I'd say it's safe to pay off the car loan.

**Read your agreement and make sure there aren't early termination / early payment fees for this.**

**Edit:**
There have been notes in the comments section's of question/answer's here about concerns with getting apartment. My two cents here: Most apartments I've seen check your credit for negative marks.

Having no credit history, and thus never missing a payment or having a judgement made against you, will likely be enough to get you into most normal-quality apartments, assuming the rest of your application / profile is in order, like:
 - Good references, if asked for them
 - At least 2.5x rent payment in gross income

etc, things like that. If they really think you're a risk, they may ask for a larger deposit (Though I'm sure in some areas there may be restrictions on whether they can do this, or how much they can do it) and still let you rent there.

Comment: The last sentence is gold!

Comment: Solid advice about the loan. Re:"If you're able to save up enough money to buy the things you want outright, credit will be of little use to you" -- OP mentions in comments wanting to get an apartment, which often involve credit checks. So there are legit reasons to care about your score to a certain extent.

Comment: This was super helpful. It seems that since I've learned about what a credit score is, people have been pounding in how important it is to have a good one. To me, using credit has never been of much interest since I prefer to wait and save until I can afford what I want. By doing this though, I felt like I was putting myself at a disadvantage when it came to things like renting. I guess I should've gone with my gut and paid cash outright for the car, haha.

Comment: Also, I just called my bank and there are no early termination, early payment, or extra payment fees.

Comment: @whrrgarbl I noticed a comment in a different answer about this, but didn't notice the OP's comment. I'll edit my response - Most apartments I've been to will accept someone with a thin profile / no credit history, as long as there are no 'negative' marks. Of course that depends on locale / region and the company providing the lease.

Comment: @A.Kirk I've had similar concerns, but have never run into issues. I personally use credit cards for most things that I purchase or pay for, and pay them off at the end of the month in full, to get whatever perks may be associated with the card(s). But I've never had a loan, and won't until I buy a house. And I've been pre-approved for quite the large home loan, upon checking, and don't anticipate any issues with getting one for the house I intend to purchase in the future. I'm certain that you'll be fine with paying off the car, opening a credit line and rarely using it.

Comment: " If you're able to save up enough money to buy the things you want outright, credit will be of little use to you." - That's not *quite* true. Having a good credit rating that you aren't using is the cheapest insurance policy possible - it costs you nothing in annual premiums, but if you *do* have the misfortune to be in an emergency situation, you can take up the credit, instead of hoping the insurer will pay out on your claim after your premiums have already "paid for your accident in advance, by installments"

Comment: @alephzero we're talking about people who are financially astute. You have given a situation with a false premise. If one has enough money to say buy items like cars outright, they also have the money to instead cover many emergencies. Given enough, they'd have assets to cover larger emergencies.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, banks will report your loan to at least one (if not all three) credit bureaus - although that is [not required by law](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/credit/lenders-report-credit-bureaus.aspx). The interest you're paying, in addition to your insurance isn't justifiable for building credit. I would recommend paying the car off and then perhaps applying for a secure credit card if you are worried about being rejected. Of course, since you have very little credit, applying for an unsecured card and getting rejected won't hurt you in the long run. If you are rejected, you can always go for a secured credit card the second time.

As I mentioned in my comments, it's better to show 6 months of on-time payments than to have no payment history at all. So if your goal is to secure an apartment near campus, I'm sure you're already a step ahead of the other students.

Answer (score 12):

Contrary to popular belief, you can build your credit (if that is important to you) without paying a penny in interest.  This is done through the responsible use of credit cards, paying the bill in full each month without accruing any interest charges.

If I were you, I would pay off the loan today, if possible.  After that, if you decide you need to build up your credit, apply for a credit card.  If you have difficulty with that, you can get a small secured credit card or retail store credit card until you have enough history to get a regular credit card.

Answer (score 6):

Your plan isn't bad, but it probably isn't worth the cost for the small amount of credit building it will achieve. If you do decide to continue with it though, you'll save in interest if you make the big payment now rather than in 6 months. In other words, you can take the minimum payment, multiply it by 5, subtract that amount from the total you owe and pay the difference immediately. This way you'll still get the 6 months of reporting to the credit bureaus, but you'll pay less interest since you'll have less principle each month.

I would recommend applying for the credit card right now. I believe you'll probably get approved now. If you do, then pay off the car loan without thinking about it. (If you don't get approved, think about it, then probably still pay it off.)

Regarding the full coverage insurance, even after the loan is paid off and you aren't required to have it, you may still want to keep it. Even if you're the best driver on earth, if someone hits you and doesn't have insurance, or they have insurance and drive off, or a deer runs in front of you, etc, you'll lose your car and won't be reimbursed. Also, as Russell pointed out in the comments below, without collision coverage your insurance company has no incentive to work on your behalf when someone else hits you, so even if it's not your fault you may still not get reimbursed. So, I wouldn't pass on the full coverage unless your car isn't worth very much or you can stomach losing it if something happens.

Good luck, and congrats on being able to pay for a car in full at 19 years old.

Comment: To your point on the insurance, though - You're paying a premium that's rigged against you either way. Your premium is calculated so that the chance of you getting hit by or hitting another car is factored into the amount they'd expect to cover for your vehicle, with whatever their expenses and profit margins are added on top of that. Theoretically, *NOT* having insurance should pay for itself over time, assuming you'd have the same number of accidents. Good reference: http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2011/06/02/insurance-a-tax-on-people-who-are-bad-at-math/

Comment: @schizoid04 Macro theory is way different from micro reality.  Statistics require a huge sample set to be anywhere near accurate.  You are a sample size of one and an insurance company has a sample size of millions.

Comment: @schizoid04 - I agree with everything you said in your comment. However, as quid points out, the word "Theoretically" in your comment is where you need to compare with "Practically" and ask yourself, "what if it happens to me?". Car accidents happen to most people at some point in their lives. This is why you need to make the decision I proposed in my second to last sentence.

Comment: The collision portion of 'full coverage' is not what covers you in any of the examples you provided. Uninsured motorist is what covers you in your first example and is relatively cheap compared to collision and hitting an animal that runs out in front of you is covered under comprehensive, again much cheaper than 'collision' insurance for a 19 year old. 

I personally never had collision until I turned 25 and had claims for both of your examples before then.

Comment: I like @Travis 's response. I suppose in my own situation, I only ever purchase cheaper vehicles (And OP didn't specify whether he bought a used / new car, so it'd be difficult for me to speculate on its value and/or replacement cost). On the off-chance that I get into some sort of accident that renders the car inoperable... I'd either pay to fix it or buy another cheap car.

Comment: @Travis - good point. I was assuming minimum liability requirements vs everything else. I suppose if "you're the best driver on earth" you would probably decide to forgo collision and perhaps just keep comprehensive.

Comment: Without full coverage, if someone hits your car, and it's clearly their fault, and they have insurance, you probably *still* won't be reimbursed, because the other insurance company will claim you're at fault and your insurance company won't argue it because they have no incentive to do so -- they aren't paying either way.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - that's an excellent point. I suppose if you don't have collision and someone hits you, you better make sure to call the police and have a report filed to make sure the other insurance company can't try that.

Comment: @TTT The other insurance company will gamble that you don't have the time and energy to go to court with it. Get full coverage.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - agreed. I incorporated your comment into my answer. Thx.

Comment: @RussellBorogove's comment is pretty much *the* reason as I see it for full coverage even on an older vehicle. Yes, you pay a bit more (for some value of "a bit"). But you do so *for the convenience if something happens*. If there is an accident that is going to be covered by *any* insurance, you can pretty much know that it will be covered by your insurance. Hence, it is in your own insurance company's interest to battle the other insurance company to get *them* to pay, instead of having to pay themselves. Either way, all *you* really have to do is file a claim with your insurance company.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I made an effort to improve my answer, please reconsider downvote or advise what you disagree. Thanks.

Comment: @Harper Please don't assume that you know who voted down a particular post. I have not, at present, downvoted *any* answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the power of capitalized interest would work in your favor and you could carry the loan paying it down while investing the original sum which would earn interest. BUT you aren't going to get any sort of return to compare with 15% so *pay off that loan immediately*.

Also contrary to popular belief (and reiterated here) paying off incurred balance on your credit card every month is responsible use of credit but it will not do much for your credit score.

The score ultimately means your ability to pay your bills and most importantly your willingness to pay interest, i.e. revolving the borrowed money. At least in the consumer market where the product they want you to buy is paying monthly interest charges.

Answer (score 2):

### Pay it off. Pay it off. Pay it off!

Credit reports have line items that, if all is well, say "paid as agreed." A car loan almost certainly gets reported. In your case it probably says the happy "paid as agreed."  It will continue to say that if you pay it off in full.

You can get the happy "paid as agreed" from a credit card too.  You can get it by paying the balance by the due date every month, or paying the mininum, or anything in between, on time. But you'll blow less money in interest if you pay each bill in full each month. You don't have to carry a balance.

In the US you can get a free credit report once a year from each of the three credit bureaus. Here's the way to do that with minimal upsell/cross-sell hassles. https://www.annualcreditreport.com/  In your situation you'd probably be smart to ask for a credit report every four months (from each bureau in turn) so you can see how things are going.  They don't give you your FICO score for free, but you don't really care about that until you're going for a big loan, like for a condo.

It might be good to take a look at one of those free credit reports real soon, as you prepare to close out your car loan.

If you need other loans, consider working with a credit union. They sometimes offer better interest rates, and they often are diligent about making credit bureau reports for their good customers; they help you build credit.

You mentioned wanting to cut back on insurance coverage. It's a worthy goal, but it's generally called "self-insuring" in the business.  If you cancel your collision coverage and then wreck your car, you absorb the cost of replacing it. So think about your personal ability to handle that kind of risk.

Comment: My bank actually allows me to see my credit score for free, updated once a month. My score was 577 before I got my car loan and it hasn't quite been a month yet so I'll see what it's like after my first payment.

Answer (score 2):

Pay it off....I've only ever paid interest on mortgages to buy the houses I've lived in (I paid both mortgages of years ahead of schedule) & as a result my credit rating's way above average, I use credit cards for everything, pay 'em off in full every month unless I'm paid not to (currently have around 8,000 sitting interest free while the cash earns 6% elsewhere). Life's sweet if you understand the system. Hell if you don't. Keep saving...

Answer (score 1):

First, **don't owe (much) money on a car that's out of warranty.**  If you have an engine blow up and repairs will cost the lion's share of the car's bluebook value, *the entire car loan immediately comes due* because the collateral is now worthless.  This puts you in a very miserable situation because you must pay off the car suddenly while also securing other transportation!

Second, watch for possible **early-payment penalties**.  They are srill lokely cheaper than paying interest, but run the numbers.  Their purpose is to repay the lender the amount of money they already paid out to the dealer in sales commission or kickback for referring the loan.

The positive effects you want for your credit report only require an open loan; owing more money doesn't help, it hurts.  However, interest is proportional to principal owed, so a $10,000 car loan is 10 times the interest cost of a $1000 car loan.  **That means paying *most* of it off early can fulfill your purpose.**

As the car is nearer payoff, you can reduce costs further (assuming you cna handle the hit) by increasing the deductible on collision and comprehensive (fire and theft) auto insurance.  It's not just you paying more co-pay, it also means the insurance company doesn't have to deal with smaller claims at all, e.g. Nodody with a $1000 deductivle files a claim on an $800 repair.

If the amount you owe is small compared to its bluebook value, and within $1000-2000 of paid off, the lender may be OK with you dropping collision and comprehensive coverage altogether (assuming you are).

All of this adds up to *paying most of it off, but not all*, may be the way to go. You could also talk to your lender about paying say, 3/4 of it off, and refinancing the rest as a 12-month deal.